# Merging 2 excel codes

Tags: excel, formula

I have two codes in two different columns, and i wanted to combine them together.

the two codes are working fine but when i try to combine them together i don't get the right output

For example the first code takes value from **CELL C6** and the code is

```
=AND(B3<=VLOOKUP(C6,Sheet3!A2:C35,3,FALSE),B3>=VLOOKUP(C6,Sheet3!A2:C35,2,FALSE))
```

And it should return either **TRUE** or **FALSE** witch it works fine.

The second code takes value from **CELL D6** and the code is

```
=AND(B3<=VLOOKUP(D6,Sheet3!A2:C35,3,FALSE),B3>=VLOOKUP(D6,Sheet3!A2:C35,2,FALSE))
```

And it should return either **TRUE** or **FALSE** witch it works fine.

But when i try to combine them together with OR Statement, the code does not work.

The combined code is

```
=OR(AND(B3<=VLOOKUP(C6,Sheet3!A2:C35,3,FALSE),B3>=VLOOKUP(C6,Sheet3!A2:C35,2,FALSE)),AND(B3<=VLOOKUP(D6,Sheet3!A2:C35,3,FALSE),B3>=VLOOKUP(D6,Sheet3!A2:C35,2,FALSE)))
```

With the combined code, i want it to return true if the **cell C6** or the **cell D6** is **true**, but code returns a strange output when both **cell C6** and **cell D6** are true which is not what i want.

The problem is the output will not retrieve TRUE unless both cells cell c6 and d6 are true other wise it will not even retrieve false, the output will just be N\A

The evaluation of the combined code is shown in this photo bellow.

[image: The combined code evaluation]

Will you help me please ?.

Comment: `or(true, true)` is true. what's strange about that?

Comment: The problem is the output will not retrieve TRUE unless both cells cell c6 and d6 are true other wise it will not even retrieve false, the output will just be N\A

Comment: If you're getting `#N/A` then one of the four vlookups is not finding a match. Wrap each in IFERROR and supply default values for no match.

Comment: I've added your comment to your post since it is an important fact that determines a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are using Vlookup with the False parameter as the fourth argument in both conditions.

If VLookup does not find an exact match, it will return #N/A!

You need to wrap each of your Vlookups into an IFError to translate that error to an empty string, so the comparison does not return an error, but a "false" instead.

```
=OR(AND(B3<=iferror(VLOOKUP(C6,Sheet3!A2:C35,3,FALSE),""),B3>=iferror(VLOOKUP(C6,Sheet3!A2:C35,2,FALSE),""),AND(B3<=iferror(VLOOKUP(D6,Sheet3!A2:C35,3,FALSE),""),B3>=iferror(VLOOKUP(D6,Sheet3!A2:C35,2,FALSE),"")))
```

I just free-handed the Iferror edits in your formula. You may want to use the formula syntax helper to place the Iferror brackets correctly.

Comment: thank you man. i already find a good solution thanks to you all

Answer (score 0):

Supply extreme values with IFERROR that will never be true to cover situations where no match is found.

```
=OR(AND(B3<=iferror(VLOOKUP(C6, Sheet3!A2:C35, 3, FALSE), -1e99), 
        B3>=iferror(VLOOKUP(C6, Sheet3!A2:C35, 2, FALSE), 1e99)),
    AND(B3<=iferror(VLOOKUP(D6, Sheet3!A2:C35, 3, FALSE), -1e99),
        B3>=iferror(VLOOKUP(D6, Sheet3!A2:C35, 2, FALSE), 1e99)))
```

Comment: but can you explain what you did exactly ?

Comment: 1e99 is scientific notation shorthand for a 1 followed by 99 zeroes, an impossibly large number. When no match is found, either 1e99 or -1e99 is defaulted so that no number in B3 would be greater or less, thus returning false.